# hash instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to use auto-generated hash'es instead of auto-incremented integers in my activerecords as primary keys. This raises two questions:

1. how to perform this generation in
   most efficient way?
2. how to handle possibility that
   generated hash exists already in
   table?

Regards, 
Mateusz

Comment: I think You should leave primary key alone for db perfomance, you should use slug, like Holde says, with primary key. For example "#{ self.id }-#{ SecureRandom.hex(4) }"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a duplicate of your question, but i think you want to do the same thing :

[Assigning Each User a Unique 100 character Hash in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125384/assigning-each-user-a-unique-100-character-hash-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: right, this covers most of my question. I will use something like: `[ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.random_bytes(35)].pack("m*").delete("\n/+=")[0..31].downcase` as I want to use it in urls.

Answer (score 9):

If you want this because you don't want to show the id in the web url. You can use a gem like https://github.com/peterhellberg/hashids.rb

It creates a reversible hash from your database id so the hash does not need to be stored in the database.

Use it in your models `to_param` method.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    Hashids.new("salt").encode(id)
  end
end
```

And decode the hash before finding the record from the database.

```
def show
  id = Hashids.new("salt").decode(params[:id]).try(:first)
  record = MyModel.find(id)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

It might not be exactly what you asked for. But I had a similar problem where I wanted to use a hash instead of the ID in the URL. My solution follows

1. I added a column in my table called privatelink
2. In my model i wrote:

```rb
  #changes the url to use privatelink instead of the id
  def to_param
    privatelink
  end

  #calls the private method set_privatelink
  before_create :set_privatelink

  private

  #generates a unique hash looking something like this: c24bea1693d9e56a1878cb83f252fba05532d9d0
  def set_privatelink
    self.privatelink = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)
  end
```

Source:
[Railcast #63 Model Name in URL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url)  - shows how to use the to_param method

Answer (score 0):

When using Oracle i had the case where I wanted to create the ID ourselves (and not use a sequence), and in [this post](http://www.dixis.com/?p=127) i provide the details how i did that. In short the code:

```
# a small patch as proposed by the author of OracleEnhancedAdapter: http://blog.rayapps.com/2008/05/13/activerecord-oracle-enhanced-adapter/#comment-240
# if a ActiveRecord model has a sequence with name "autogenerated", the id will not be filled in from any sequence
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.class_eval do
  alias_method :orig_next_sequence_value, :next_sequence_value

  def next_sequence_value(sequence_name)
    if sequence_name == 'autogenerated'
      # we assume id must have gotten a good value before insert!
      id
    else
      orig_next_sequence_value(sequence_name)
    end
  end
end
```

while this solution is specific to Oracle-enhanced, i am assuming inside the other adapters you can overrule the same method (`next_sequence_value`).

Comment: Oh thanks. For postgresql I used [this link](http://www.gnegg.ch/2011/03/rails-postgresql-and-the-native-uuid-type/). it also overwrites ConnectionAdapter. For now I generate uuids in rails using uuidtools gem, as I dont want to install additional modules to postgresql. Oracle version might be very useful in future.

Comment: Good link. So you still have an `:id` and an extra `:uuid` field. Maybe that is indeed the best solution. The idea i offered was that you would overwrite the normal `:id`, which is normally filled from a sequence, with a value you generate yourself. To be complete: i think you should provide it as an answer to your own question. Native uuid generation is indeed an optimal solution. Let the database do the heavy lifting.

Comment: you are right, your answer is most correct when it comes to oracle. It doesn't provide solution for other databases unfortunately. 

Why I left :id?
a) as most of comments in internet shows using uuid's as primary key slows down database with huge sets of data. 
b) from rails framework point of view using something else then auto_incremented integer values as primary key is wrongdoing.

Comment: Those are definitely valid points. The case where i needed was because we were using Rails on top of a legacy db.